# How do I implement a trait for a type with "rented" reference

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

NB: I tried to keep this post as concise as possible, the full code can be found at https://github.com/pchampin/pair_trait.

## The problem

I have defined the following trait:

```
pub trait Pair {
    type Item: Borrow<str>;
    fn first(&self) -> &Self::Item;
    fn second(&self) -> &Self::Item;
}
```

I have generic implementations of this trait for `(T,T)` and `[T;2]` for any T implementing `Borrow<str>`.

I also have a type, built with the [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) crate, containing a `String` and two `Cow<str>` that borrow from that string:

```
#[rental(covariant)]
pub struct SelfSustainedPair {
    line: String,
    pair: (Cow<'line, str>, Cow<'line, str>),
}
```

I would like this type to implement the `Pair` trait above, but I can't find a way to do it.

## Attempt #0

```
impl SelfSustainedPair {
    pub fn first(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().first() }
    pub fn second(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().second() }
}
```

I know that this is not an implementation of the trait,
but I just wanted to be sure that I could implement the methods `first` and `second`. The answer is yes: the code above compiles.

## Attempt #1

```
impl Pair for SelfSustainedPair {
    type Item = Cow<str>;
    fn first(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().first() }
    fn second(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().second() }
}
```

This fails to compile, with the message "expected lifetime parameter" for the 2nd line.

This is frustrating because it is so close to attempt #0 above.

## Attempt #2

```
impl<'a> Pair for SelfSustainedPair {
    type Item = Cow<'a, str>;
    fn first(&self) -> &Cow<'a, str> { self.suffix().first() }
    fn second(&self) -> &Cow<'a, str> { self.suffix().second() }
}
```

Here the compiler is complaining about an "unconstrainted lifetime parameter" for the first line (`impl<'a>`).

## Attempt #3

I modified my trait `Pair` so that it expects a lifetime parameter. Surprisingly, this works, even if the liferime parameter is never used in the definition of the trait...

I then wrote:

```
impl<'a> Pair<'a> for SelfSustainedPair {
    type Item = Cow<'a, str>;
    fn first(&self) -> &Cow<'a, str> { self.suffix().first() }
    fn second(&self) -> &Cow<'a, str> { self.suffix().second() }
}
```

Now the compiler complains that it "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref" in both methods...

Anyway, my intuition is that this is not the right path: the lifetime for which the returned `Cow` can not be specified independantly of that of `self`...

## Attempt #4

Ideally, this is what I would like to write:

```
impl Pair for SelfSustainedPair {
    type Item = Cow<'self, str>;
    fn first(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().first() }
    fn second(&self) -> &Cow<str> { self.suffix().second() }
}
```

but obviously, the compiler doesn't know about the `self` lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the fully intended design is currently unachievable. Still, we can adapt attempt #3 to *sort-of* work.

The idea of returning a `&Self::Item` is slightly ill-formed, because the associated type `Item` already represents a borrowed value. It makes more sense to return it directly:

```
pub trait Pair {
    type Item: Borrow<str>;
    fn first(&self) -> Self::Item;
    fn second(&self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

But then you would stumble with the incapability of describing this `Item` as a `Cow<'a, str>` where `'a` is the lifetime of `self`. Attempt 3 was close to a solution by adding a lifetime parameter to the trait itself, thus making this arbitrary lifetime a higher-ranked argument to the trait.

```
pub trait Pair<'a> {
    type Item: 'a + Borrow<str>;
    fn first(&'a self) -> Self::Item;
    fn second(&'a self) -> Self::Item;
}
```

This `Pair<'a>` now defines a pair of elements bound to `'a`, and are not necessarily contained by `self`. One possible implementation:

```
impl<'a> Pair<'a> for (String, String) {
    type Item = Cow<'a, str>;

    fn first(&'a self) -> Self::Item {
        Cow::Borrowed(&self.0)
    }
    fn second(&'a self) -> Self::Item {
        Cow::Borrowed(&self.1)
    }
}
```

[Full example in the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fde47beade53a2821c14b80ba4e508d1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This approach comes at the expense of polluting all APIs relying on this trait with higher ranked trait bounds, so that we can implement `Pair<'a>` for all lifetimes `'a`. For example:

```
fn foo<T>(pair: T)
where
    for<'a> T: Pair<'a>,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

---

In order to achieve this `'self` lifetime for constraining the associated type `Item`, we need [Generic Associated Types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) (GATs). Once implemented, we'll be able to write something like this:

```
pub trait Pair {
    type Item<'a>: Borrow<str>;
    fn first(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a>;
    fn second(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a>;
}

impl Pair for (String, String) {
    type Item<'a> = Cow<'a, str>;

    fn first(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a> {
        Cow::Borrowed(&self.0)
    }
    fn second(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a> {
        Cow::Borrowed(&self.1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to consider this (rather convoluted) problem. You did crack it! What kept me away from Attempt #3 was indeed the polution of the API, and I didn't know the trick of using "for <'a>". Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, I implemented your solution in my github example project: https://github.com/pchampin/pair_trait

Comment: As an aside, I disagree with you when you write that "the idea of returning a &Self::Item is slightly ill-formed, because the associated type Item already represents a borrowed value". Borrow<str> is not a borrowed value, it is something *from which* a str can be borrowed. In case, for example, Item = String, I don't want the String to be copied, I just want a reference.